# facing problem starting create-react-app npm start. throws an error

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am trying to create a new react project below steps:

1. npx create-react-app react-new-app
2. cd react-new-app
3. npm start

my node version v16.13.0, npm version 8.1.0

running `npm start` throws en error:

`   'library' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'G:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)        
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at      node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
```

code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
requireStack: []
}
`

then I tried some online solution

1. delete node_modules
2. delete package-lock.json
3. npm install

but it never works!

Comment: Very strange. I just created a test app and it seems to be working fine. What is the output of `npm install` for you? Also, if possible, please add the output of `npx create-react-app ...`. If it is a new project, just delete it and use the following command to create: `npx create-react-app@latest react-new-app`. This will make sure to pick the latest `cra` version.

Comment: okk this is happening because i installed my node on my /E drive. and my project was /G drive. so, it didn't work. Now working as my project and node are in the same drive. Thank you